# Can’t upvote or downvote any answer or question

Tags: support

For some weeks now, if I try to upvote an answer I get a modal box saying “Request failed”. This happens all over Stack Exchange.

The message box also says I should report this on meta, so now I do that.

Comment: Hi Wirewrap, thank you for bringing this up. Since you say this is happening across the Stack Exchange network, I think it would be best to ask this question on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you using the old app or the website? The app is slowing being dismantled and has lost the function to vote already.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Yep, using an ipad app so that was it, thanks. Slightly remarkable I had not seen  information about this before.

Comment: See [this post about the mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned/383038#383038) on Meta

Answer (score 3):

Sorry you're having problems using Aviation.

The popup is pointing you towards [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) which is the central stackexchange meta site, where you can tag your question with a tag `support` which says:

> Use this tag for requests for assistance with tools and other features on the Stack Exchange Network. This includes understanding how features work and why they work that way, or how to better use them.